# Table with fixed thead with horizontal and vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

I have calendar with list of users in left side and in right side - dates with cell. On top I need fix dates when scroll page to bottom. I don't know how I can make it because I have `<table>` with dates in main `<table>` with `overflow: scroll`, because I need scroll and fixed left-side-users.

How I can fix `<thead>` with dates on top when scrolling to bottom of page? It's now simple `position: absolute;` because I have nested table and `overflow: scroll;`. Split table with dates on thead and tbody in two different tables? And catch event `scroll` and apply this to other table?

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/p69j0L5h/2/

P.S. In real situation all cells are equal (about width and height). This is just example.

Comment: Is there a requirement to structure them in this way? Nesting the tables really complicated the 'freezing' of rows (the effect you want for the dates row) It can be done, but it seems like a much more inconvenient & inefficient solution than what I'd propose.

Comment: There is (rather old) jquery plugin for this purpose. https://plugins.jquery.com/table-scroll/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposition -can- work, but that doesn't mean you should do it that way. Horribly complicated markup, and you're splitting your tabular data in a way that makes it less appropriate for tables.

Bi-axial sticky/frozen headers are very possible and quite do-able.

Please refer to this link: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/StickyTableHeaders/index3.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```css
//makes thead stay in fixed position
thead {
 position: fixed;
}

//makes td 100px wide
td {
 width: 100px;  
}

//makes scroll bar on bottom appear up top
table {
 height: 200px; /*think that 100% would work too*/
}
```

Comment: What this? Show me jsfiddle please

Answer (score 0):

With changes in your html layout, I could achieve what you wanted! But I am not sure if this is the correct way.

The html will look like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container main">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr class="fixed">
      <th>blank space</th>
        <th ng-repeat="date in dates">
          {{date}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

  </table>
  <table  class="table table-bordered" style="margin-top:50px">
     <tbody style="margin-top:30px">
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
        <td>{{user}}</td>
        <td  ng-repeat="date in dates"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I have created a fiddle of the same: https://jsfiddle.net/gpa5v9L7/

Comment: And where is horizontal scroll and overflow?

Comment: cells in main table are don't move

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are saying the headers (dates) don't scroll! There is horizontal scroll at the bottom which can be used to scroll through dates and the vertical scroll is to scroll through users!